# Ruby on Rails, Low Pro, and JQuery (through JRails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-plugins, lowpro

I am using [JRails](http://ennerchi.com/projects/jrails) with Ruby on Rails so that I can simply use jQuery since I am more familiar with it. I am also attempting to use [Low Pro](http://github.com/danwrong/low-pro-for-jquery/tree/master/) to submit some of my forms remotely.

I am currently running into an interesting problem that has me stumped. I have added the following to my `application.js` file and I know that these are working correctly because I am seeing the response returned (using Firebug in Firefox):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  dataType: "script"
});

$(function() {
  $('a.remote').attach(Remote.Link);
  $('form.remote').attach(Remote.Form);
});
```

All I have to do is add `class="remote"` to my links and my forms and everything works great. The `dataType: "script"` part makes sure that it does an `eval()` on the returned response text so that it can update the page correctly.

So, I have a simple link that creates a new shipment. In my `new.js.rjs` file I have the following:

```
page.insert_html :bottom, '#shipments_table',
    :partial => 'test', :locals => { :shipment => @shipment }
```

If I replace this with `page.visual_effect :fade, '#shipments_table'` it does that as you would expect. If my `_test.html.erb` file is fairly simple, it also works. The problem is when I attempt to add a `<form>` to my partial. Different problems arise depending upon the placement of the `<form>` tags. For example, this

```
<tr>
  <form>
    <td>Some Text</td> 
  </form>
</tr>
```

and this

```
<form>
  <tr> 
    <td>Some Text</td> 
  </tr>
</form>
```

make absolutely nothing appear. This

```
<form></form>
<tr> 
  <td>Some Text</td> 
</tr>
```

will make `Some Text` appear, but it loses all of my formatting. And this

```
<tr> 
  <td>Some Text</td> 
</tr>
<form></form>
```

works exactly how I need (visually speaking). However, the obvious downside to this is that I can't put my form inputs into the table columns, which basically makes the whole process useless. I can probably work around this by simply putting them all on one line inside of a `<div>` or something similar, but I would prefer that everything be aligned.

Any ideas as to how to solve this conundrum would be greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<form>` should only be placed inside the `<td>` or wrap the `<table>`:

```
<form><table/></form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the idea is that the user will be able to add multiple ones simultaneously, which means that all forms would be wrapping all form elements, which wouldn't work.

Comment: After a bit of searching, I found out that you simply arent' allowed to put a form tag inside a table like I was attempting. So I am now simply putting the inputs inside the table and I will use JavaScript to serialize/send the data since it degrades to using plain HTML if JavaScript isn't available. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use tables you will need to do as tom said and wrap the table element with the form element, or put it inside the td element(s).

Alternatively you could abandon tables for lining things up and use the label element instead:

```
<style type="text/css">
label{
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input, textarea{
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

textarea{
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}

.boxes{
    width: 1em;
}

#submitbutton{
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 90px;
}

br{
    clear: left;
}
</style>
<form>
<label for="user">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="" /><br />
</form>
```

http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/tableless_forms/

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that **tr** elements just don't expect **form** children and that the browser is getting muddled.  That means that if you put the **table** tag *within* the **form** tag it should solve the problem.  If you can't do that because there's other forms dotted around then try nesting it within the **td** elements instead.

In the last two examples the form and table are siblings, not parent/child, so any transition performed on one might not effect the other as you expect.

If it's still not working then it might be to do with how **form** elements are treated in the documents flow.  Try wrapping the whole thing in a **div** and applying the transition to that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the div wrapping a try when I get to work tomorrow and post some more info/accept an answer if it works!